# Multilingual site body class

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n

I am creating a multilingual site using the [Internationalize](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module for Drupal 7. A lot of the CSS on my site is dependent on the body class section-... I have a page called Solutions which has a body class of section-solutions, I have multiple styles that use that selector.  When I switch to Protugues that selector changes to section-soluções and all my styles are gone.  Is there any way to keep all the HTML on the page in English?